# How to convert JSON string to a JSON object

Tags: python, json

I need to convert a JSON string to a JSON object in Python.

My JSON string looks like

```
'{"button1": "yes", "channel": "rules-test-channel"}'
```

I need to convert this string to a JSON object where my end result should look like

```
{"button1": "yes", "channel": "rules-test-channel"}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: The duplicate is a bit overly complicated. Point is, just use `json.loads`.